# How to programmatically print a webform block with caching enabled?

Tags: 8, webforms, caching

When displaying a Webform inside a normal block (using `admin/structure/block`) Drupal manage to correctly cache the page, the HTTP header displays `X-Drupal-Dynamic-Cache: HIT`.

However we need to display this webform inside a paragraph so we tried the following :

- use twig_tweak module and `{{ drupal_block('webform_...') }}`
- programmatically put the block in a template preprocess like this :

```
$my_form = \Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform::load('contact_new');
$output = \Drupal::entityManager()
          ->getViewBuilder('webform')
          ->view($my_form);
$variables['contact_form'] = $output;
```

Both solutions seem to make the page uncacheable: `X-Drupal-Dynamic-Cache: UNCACHEABLE`.

What would be the correct way to put a block in a paragraph while make the page cacheable ?
How to mimic the standard block system to display a in our template ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dynamic Page Cache needs to placeholder the dynamic part and it can only do so when it is built in a lazy builder:

*/mymodule/src/WebformLazyBuilder.php*

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule;

use Drupal\Core\Render\Element\RenderCallbackInterface;

class WebformLazyBuilder implements RenderCallbackInterface {

  public static function buildWebform($webform) {
    return  [
      'webform' => [
        '#type' => 'webform',
        '#webform' => $webform,
      ],
    ];
  }

}
```

Then you can put the lazy builder in a template preprocess hook:

```
$variables['contact_form'] =  [
  '#lazy_builder' => ['\Drupal\mymodule\WebformLazyBuilder::buildWebform', ['contact']],
  '#create_placeholder' => TRUE,
];
```

Blocks are placed in a lazy builder by default, see [BlockViewBuilder::viewMultiple](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21src%21BlockViewBuilder.php/function/BlockViewBuilder%3A%3AviewMultiple/9.0.x).

Comment: Your example code is making think we could provide optional lazy builder support for all webform instances.  For example, we would add a '#lazy_builder': true property to the Webform element, which returns a lazy builder instead of the webform.

Comment: @jrockowitz, that sounds like a great idea, the element base class is already implementing RenderCallbackInterface, so we could place the lazy builder callback directly in the webform element class.

Comment: Thank you, that is a great answer :)

Comment: @4k4 see https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3164675